# Weaviate vector type

Tags: weaviate

Is it possible to change the datatype of an vector?
When I for instance trying to save following object to /batch/objects

```js
{
    "fields": [
        "ALL"
    ],
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": "1112a0911b90de8277fc3fb45c97d3c3",
            "vector": [
              0.11111111111122222
            ],
            "class": "Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Only 0.11111111 is being saved as the vector and I suppose it is because the datatype is float32

Answer (score 0):

I think you've set the vector as a normal data type.

As you can see in the example below (from [this demo dataset](https://demo.dataset.playground.semi.technology/v1/objects/000e4e5f-40a8-3981-ba08-2407c92efa6c?include=vector)), you can see that what you call `objects` actually has an objects `properties`. It seems that you've set your vector as an array in `properties`.

This [Weaviate Core Knowledge section](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/current/core-knowledge/basics.html#vectors) in the documentation might also be helpful.

```js
{
    "class": "Article",
    "creationTimeUnix": 1664505085008,
    "id": "000e4e5f-40a8-3981-ba08-2407c92efa6c",
    "lastUpdateTimeUnix": 1664505086123740200,
    "properties": {
        "inPublication": [
            {
                "beacon": "weaviate://localhost/16476dca-59ce-395e-b896-050080120cd4",
                "href": "/v1/objects/16476dca-59ce-395e-b896-050080120cd4"
            }
        ],
        "summary": "Mission accomplished for Florida International's James Morgan, Charlotte's Benny LeMay and Navy's Malcolm Perry in the East-West Shrine Bowl. The trio shined for the East in a 31-27 victory, with Morgan leading two first-quarter touchdown drives and LeMay rushing for a pair of TDs, including the game-winner. Perry took a direct snap from center and sprinted 52 yards for a TD on his only carry. Robinson, who rushed for 1,899 yards and 18 touchdowns for Illinois State this season, finished with 80 yards rushing on seven attempts. Stevens also had an 18-yard completion to Rhode Island's Aaron Parker to set up LeMay's second touchdown.",
        "title": "LeMay's 2 TDs lead East over West 31-27 in Shrine Bowl",
        "url": "http://www.foxnews.com/sports/lemays-2-tds-lead-east-over-west-31-27-in-shrine-bowl",
        "wordCount": 411
    },
    "vector": [
        -0.09015006,
        0.11759494,
        0.024284547,
        // etc   
    ]
}
```

Comment: My question was a bit badly asked, sorry for that. But my request was when im trying to save a custom vector with the /batch/objects endpoint not all decimals are saved in weaviate. If you wanna save vectors with more decimals, is that possible?